# Is there an expand.grid like function in R, returning permutations?

Tags: r, permutation, combinations

to become more specific, here is an example:

```
> expand.grid(5, 5, c(1:4,6),c(1:4,6))
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     5    5    1    1
2     5    5    2    1
3     5    5    3    1
4     5    5    4    1
5     5    5    6    1
6     5    5    1    2
7     5    5    2    2
8     5    5    3    2
9     5    5    4    2
10    5    5    6    2
11    5    5    1    3
12    5    5    2    3
13    5    5    3    3
14    5    5    4    3
15    5    5    6    3
16    5    5    1    4
17    5    5    2    4
18    5    5    3    4
19    5    5    4    4
20    5    5    6    4
21    5    5    1    6
22    5    5    2    6
23    5    5    3    6
24    5    5    4    6
25    5    5    6    6
```

This data frame was created from all combinations of the supplied vectors. I would like to create a similar data frame from all `permutations` of the supplied vectors. Notice that each row must contain exactly 2 fives, yet not necessarily the fist two in line.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you show what you want the output to look like?  Permutations typically act on sets, not on sets of sets, so I'm not sure what the function should do.

Comment: @Ken Williams, To give another example, apart from the pair 5,5,1,2 and 5,5,2,1 I would also like in the resultset 5,1,5,2 - 5,2,5,1 - 5,1,2,5 - 5,2,1,5 - 1,5,2,5 - 2,5,1,5 - 1,5,5,2 - 2,5,5,1 - 1,2,5,5 and 2,1,5,5. If I am correct, the resulting dataframe's dimension should be: [150,4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works. (relies on permutations from gtools)

```
comb <- t(as.matrix(expand.grid(5, 5, c(1:4,6),c(1:4,6))))
perms <- t(permutations(4,4))
ans <- apply(comb,2,function(x) x[perms])
ans <- unique(matrix(as.vector(ans), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
```

Comment: Excellent! I find it strange that there is not such a function built in

Comment: Why should it be built in?  What's wrong with having that in an external package?

Answer (score 0):

Try `?allPerms` in the `vegan` package.